# Problem with the baking from multires

Tags: texture-baking

[image][image]

I can actually bake the normal map from multires, but at viewport shading mode I can't see the result

Comment: are you sure that there's any detail on your normal map? But maybe pack your image and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: thanks for reply this is the ports of object https://pasteall.org/blend/53c384e8c5c345c790af5b6d10653568

Comment: thanks but you need to pack your image before saving: File > External Data > Pack Resources

Comment: sorry for the w8ing it got more than 24mb so it took time here you go https://pasteall.org/blend/41fc87a3bea7476ab6471ff86c7feaad

Comment: See my edit, you need to enable the good UV map

Comment: this uv is just for example in my real file i used uv packer so the uv is ok the problem is at material preview mode the normal map looks wierd

Comment: it looks weird maybe because your first unwrap is bad, take a look at the UV Editor, the UV islands seem completely collapsed no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've done a second unwrap, this is the one you need to enable:

[image]

Your first unwrap seems pretty unusable, see how it looks, the islands are completely collapsed in the bottom left of the image, therefore your current result:

[image]

Comment: aw sorry wrong picture post, actually its connected to normal , dont know why only this object's bake from multires doesnt work. like you see other objects work well

Comment: omg thanks that was the problem didnt now i have 2 uvmaps... it was my first time to us uv-packer. thanks guys for the help